# What is equivalent of val bundle = bundleOf(..) for communication between fragments in java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm learning navigation component in android. What is the equivalent of val bundle = bundleOf(..) for communication between fragments in java?

Comment: you mean bundle = new Bundle() and then bundle.putExtra()

Comment: bundleOf is a extension method for Kotlin, in Java you instantiate a Bundle object then add the values with putExtra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good reference here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating

As a summary, you can instantiate and send a bundle to the fragment like this:

```
// Create fragment and give it an argument for the selected article
ArticleFragment newFragment = new ArticleFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt(ArticleFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
newFragment.setArguments(args);
```

Also for communication, the fragment can invoke callbacks in the parent defining an interface in the fragment and implementing it in the parent.